# Selenium IEdriver NoSuchElementException exceptionally

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I encountered this kinda behavior with IE selenium driver - I am using TEST CASE code generated by `Selenium IDE` - within `Firefox` works fine.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/RZR/1.5.85/ZobrazitReklamaceROB.aspx");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_identifikaceROB_rbAIFO")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_identifikaceROB_tbAIFO")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_identifikaceROB_tbAIFO")).SendKeys("pqrJrJxtt/qUvjhO8=");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_identifikaceROB_btnVyhledat")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_identifikaceROB_btnVyhledat")).Click();
//Actions action = new Actions(driver);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
//action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_gvPrehled_ctl04_selectButton10168579135")).Click();
```

With `IEDriver` however - if i run this code under `VS2013`

1. In debug with breakpoints and going through step by step - it does work
2. If i let test go without stepping and breakpoints then `NoSuchElementFindException` will occurred at

driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_identifikaceROB_tbAIFO")).Clear();

in case

1. This normally happened - test passes moreover each time - however sometimes not with `NoSuchElementFindException`

Colleagues gave me advice to navigate to components(TB in this case) with tab keys - so far unsuccessful as well, but trying this way.

Using latest update of IE, ZOOM 100%, registry alternation according to selenium webpage, protection mode is set same for all zones.

Any idea or same experience?

Update:

Initialization:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{

    var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
    {
        IgnoreZoomLevel = true
    };

    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(".", options);

    baseURL = "http://vm-kzr-dev/";
    verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Comment: Have you verified the `Security Zone` settings?

Comment: they are set to minimal level if possible

Comment: They all have to be checked or unchecked. NOT BOTH. See [this](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html)

Comment: you mean "unable protected zone" - are all unchecked

Comment: Yes. If so can you please provide the code block where you instantiate IEDriver including any profiler settings

Comment: question updated, imho there isn't much to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an issue. You need to disable IE native events.

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnableNativeEvents = false;
```

See [this](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html) for understanding how native events is related to IEDriver.

I would also suggest you to remove redundant `ignoreZoomLevel` and replace that with `EnableNativeEvents`

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
{
    EnableNativeEvents = false
};
```

Comment: And why exactly would turning off native events fix the problem reported by the OP?

Comment: @Louis it's a generic issue with `IEDriver`'s `click()` event. Have you gone through the reference I provide? That would certainly explain better than I can right here. :D

Comment: Yes, I've read that article a while back and reread it before posting my earlier comment. I've got a pair of test suites with (lemme check...) over 800 and 600 steps (one step can contain multiple Selenium commands, many of which are `click()`), both run fine with IE with native events turned on. In fact, if I *do* turn off native events, they will fail (in all browsers) because native events can simulate things that synthetic events cannot.

Comment: @Louis Also see this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116#c21).

Comment: And, just for clarification, my answer was provided specifically for `IEDriver` only. I am not suggesting OP to disable native events for other drivers

Comment: Disabling Native events worked for me so far :-), thanks for all contribution guys!!!

Comment: @PetrKováč Good to hear that. Please don't forget to upvote as well if this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

IE seems to be slower and if the test is passing with Firefox then IE is rendering the page slower in which case you can use

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_gvPrehled_ctl04_selectButton10168579135")));
```